# sticky footer display table not working on Firefox / IE

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm developing a basic sticky footer template using `display: table` technique. It works just fine in Chrome, but in **Firefox** and **IE** is not: footer is pushed away by the content.

Clearly i'm missing something basic here, i'm kinda newbie in CSS, so forgive me.

Here it is some code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header" class="row">Header</div>
    <div id="content" class="row">
        <p>some content 1</p>
        <p>some content 2</p>
        <p>some content 3</p>
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="row">Footer</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
html, body{ 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.row{
    display: table-row;
    position: relative;
}
#header, #footer{
    height: 50px;
}
#content{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7ftmyd4L/2/)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `float:left` from `#content`:

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ftmyd4L/4/)

**Update**

Given the need for a scrollable middle part and your fixed height header and footer,  I would use fixed positioning instead of display:table;

```css
#header, #footer, #content {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
#header, #footer {
    background:red;
}
#header {
    top:0;
    height:50px;
}
#footer {
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
}
#content {
    top:50px; /*height of header*/
    bottom:50px; /*height of footer*/
    overflow:auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="row">Header</div>
<div id="content" class="row">
            <p>some content 1</p>
            <p>some content 2</p>
            <p>some content 3</p>
            <p>some content 4</p>
            <p>some content 5</p>
            <p>some content 6</p>
            <p>some content 1</p>
            <p>some content 2</p>
            <p>some content 3</p>
            <p>some content 4</p>
            <p>some content 5</p>
            <p>some content 6</p>
            <p>some content 1</p>
            <p>some content 2</p>
            <p>some content 3</p>
            <p>some content 4</p>
            <p>some content 5</p>
            <p>some content 6</p>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="row">Footer</div>
```

Comment: if i remove it then won't work as expected: header and footer should be always visible  with a fixed height, and content should resize automatically with the overflow scrollable. Try resizing window height in my example with chrome.. that is the desired behaviour. Thanks

Comment: I've just had a look and that wasn't very cross browser friendly.  Is your header and footer a fixed height?

Comment: yes they have fixed height, and the content should fill the remaining height (enabling scroll if content height > available height)

Comment: in which case you would probably be better off using fixed positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/7ftmyd4L/14/

Comment: that's perfect, thanks. If you update your answer i'll mark as correct